# I want to know if exist a vulnerability in using sp_send_dbmail of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-injection, smtp, sql-server, programming

I'm using the next stored procedure  `sp_send_dbmail` in SQL Server 2012, the DBA ask me if it possible make SQL Injection using this SP, or SMTP Injection?

In the configuration of the

> Database Mail Profile and Account

We use Anonymous Authentication and we have a default profile to send emails.

Best regards.